# Apelido de expressão com SUM não está funcionando

Tags: mysql, sql, banco-de-dados

Estou tentando fazer um `SUM` em uma *query* que executa alguns cálculos. Segue o exemplo:

```
SELECT
 SUM ( (qtd - qtd_devolucao) * valor AS total)
FROM
 produtos
WHERE
 id_pedido = '47'
```

Estou tendo o seguinte erro:

> #1064 - Você tem um erro de sintaxe no seu SQL próximo a 'AS total)

Comment: Você quer que a soma se chame `total`?

Comment: Quero somar todos os `total`

Comment: E qual é a expressão que forma o `total`?

Comment: Quero que o `total` recebe `(qtd - qtd_devolucao) * valor` Depois quero dar um `sum` no `total`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Para dar um nome para a soma ela deve estar fora do parenteses, deve ser a última coisa da expressão:

```
SELECT SUM((qtd - qtd_devolucao) * valor) AS total
   FROM produtos
   WHERE id_pedido = '47'
```

[Veja funcionando no **SQL Fiddle**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/dd6219/3). Também [coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/SQL/Select/SyntaxAliasExpression.sql).

Comment: Não deu certo, continua com o mesmo erro.

Comment: @HugoBorges coloquei um Fiddle mostrando que funciona, você deve estar fazendo errado, ou a pergunta está errada.

Comment: Desculpa, o erro realmente foi meu. Funcionou 100%, obrigado.